# How to label return key in custom keyboard based on text input type

Tags: objective-c, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I am creating a custom keyboard.  I have a button for Return/Go/etc.  If the user is entering a URL, my button text should be "Go". If she is writing in note, it should be "Return".

How can my keyboard extension figure out what label to put on the button?

Answer (score 4):

Your text document proxy conforms to [`UITextInputTraits`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIReturnKeyType), so you want to use `self.textDocumentProxy.returnKeyType` or `.keyboardType`.